# DatagridView image cell click view image in full size in another form

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

Greetings everyone i want to click an image in my datagridview then it will display it in another form in full size.

the problem is the image it self is populated from mysql table

and i have read other questions that carry the same meaning but all of them were data that came from local table and not mysql table.

here is my dataset

```
Con.Open();
            string Myquery = "select * from SampleTable";
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(Myquery, Con);
            MySqlCommandBuilder builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            ProductsGv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            imageColumn = (DataGridViewImageColumn)ProductsGv.Columns[1];
```

Thank you.
note: there is a con close at the end of the code i just didnt post it here because there are too many lines where i manipulated the columns size width and name

Comment: What is the DataSource of your DGV? Or, did you add Rows *manually*? I.e., did you convert the byte array to an Image yourself? Other?

Comment: @Jimi the datasource of my dgv is coming from mysql table i didnt add any rows they are all populated from the mysql table and iam not sure but iam using this code to view it in dgv

`DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
                imageColumn = (DataGridViewImageColumn)ProductsGv.Columns[1];`

Comment: You can add in the `CellClick` or `CellContentClick` handlers something like: `if (ProductsGv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewImageCell cell) { var image = cell.FormattedValue as Image; }`